# AWS Cloudformation - unable to refer a resource in the Swagger from a nested stack

Tags: swagger, aws-cloudformation

I'm facing some issues on aws Cloudformation. I'm trying to incorporate nested stacks as I have exhausted the 200 resource limit. This is what I have as an example

**Stack A - Parent stack which has an API Resource**

```
RestAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Sub ${Stage}
      DefinitionBody:
        Fn::Transform:
          Name: AWS::Include
          Parameters:
            Location:
              - Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - 's3://'
                  - Ref: S3BucketName
                  - '/swagger.yaml'

GetLogs:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: Logs_Lambda/index.getHandler
      Role: !GetAtt RDSLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Events:
        GetUsers:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: management/logs
            Method: get
            RestApiId: !Ref RestAPI
```

**Stack B - A Child stack of Stack A**

```
LambdaSaveLogsInvokePermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    FunctionName: !Ref SaveLogs
    Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
    Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com

SaveLogs:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    FunctionName: SaveLogs
    CodeUri:
      Bucket: !Ref BuildBucketName
      Key: !Ref BuildObjectKey
    Handler: logs_Lambda/index.saveHandler
    Role: !Ref RDSLambdaExecutionRoleArn
    Events:
      SaveLogs:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: management/logs/save
          Method: post
          RestApiId: !Ref RestAPI
```

My swagger files has these references

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: 
            Fn::Sub: "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${SaveLogs.Arn}/invocations"

x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: 
            Fn::Sub: "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${GetLogs.Arn}/invocations"
```

Note that stack B is referencing the RestAPI resource which is passed as a parameter from Stack A

**My Problems and What I tried**

- The create changeset fails when the code pipeline executes saying it cannot
  find the any reference to SaveLogs.Arn. Which I think is Stack A
  embeds the code into the RestAPI and hence it cannot find a reference
  for the resource of a childstack
- So I did an output from the Stack B for the SaveLogs Arn and updated the swagger file to refer the output. It then gave an error on the changeset that said "Circular dependency between resources" (which sounds right too)
- I then did and export of the SaveLogs Arn resource which then
  succeeded the create changeset but failed at the deploy changeset.

**Questions**

- My question is how do we overcome this?
- Is there a way to use a    different swagger file for each stack
  somehow?
- Is there a different    way of writing nested stack for    APIs
  thinking  of scalebility?

Would anyone be able to comment or help with this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this

You have to package the nested template first and store the output yml file in s3 and provide that as the s3 template location in the nested stack definition.

NestedStack:
Type: 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
DeletionPolicy: Retain
Properties:
TemplateURL: >-
https://s3-bucket-name/template-export.yml

template-export.yml is the output template once you package your original nested template

You should add the output to your child stack like this

Outputs:
SaveLogsNested:
Value: !GetAtt SaveLogs.Arn

Also, the URI should be specified like this:
"x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
"type": "aws_proxy",
"uri": {
"Fn::Join": [
"",
[
"arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/",
{
"Fn::GetAtt" : [
"NestedStack",
"Outputs.SaveLogsNested"
]
},
"/invocations"
]
]
}